# Optimizing sybase SQL Query

Tags: t-sql, sap-ase

Is there a way to optimize the following query:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET Calculation =
  (SELECT MAX(Calculation)
   FROM myTable T
   WHERE T.Id = myTable.Id
     AND T.Flag='N')
WHERE Calculation='NA'
  AND Flag='Y'
```

where myTable has approx. 4 million rows? Actually the first not NULL will do the job (SYBASE ASE 15.0.2).

Answer (score 0):

Check Query plan, it must be using deferred update which is taking longer time to update.
Query suggested by Michael should perform better.

rememeber below points which require deferred update

- Updates that use self-joins
- Updates to columns used for self-referential integrity
- Updates to a table referenced in a correlated subquery

Thanks..